# Jingle on ASmack - XMPP

Tags: xmpp, smack, asmack

Does anybody can provide some tip about how to use Jingle on XMPP - precisely on ASmack as I develop for Android. I saw source code of ASmack and there is lib for JSTUN so it's implemented.

Any code/tip/link would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smack's Jingle code is pretty old and lacks a current maintainer. I can't say if it's working right now or how far it has been diverged from the specification.

There is ["Java-Bells: A Jingle implementation for Java based on LibJitsi, Ice4J and Smack"](http://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/50298), but I can't comment on Java-Bells fitness for Android.

I know that there are many people out there looking for a out-of-the-box working solution for Jingle on Android. But AFAIK, at the time of writing, there is none.

Comment: Can you update your answer. I want to develop application in jingle using smack, but I its doc I read that the code is not maintain and old. Can you guide me if there is no problem of using smack jingle or there is better solution. https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/gettingstarted.html

Comment: Yes sure, Answer is correct.. I want to extend the answer :) through my question in comment :) .. I will really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Here you is the implementation of WebRTC + Jingle which is support Android and iOS also

[Webrtc audio + jingle protocol brought to IOS and Android](https://github.com/lukeweber/webrtc-jingle-client)